# integral calculate $f:[e,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$f:[e,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$  $f(x)=\frac{1}{xlnx}$

I want to show $\int_{[e,\infty)} f d\lambda$  and I know it has to be $=\infty$
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Monotone Convergence Theorem we know that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{e}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x\ln x}d\lambda=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{e}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x\ln x}dx.
\end{align*}
The function $\dfrac{1}{x\ln x}$ is continuous on $[e,n]$, so the Lebesgue integral and Riemann integral coincide, we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to compute that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{e}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x\ln x}d\lambda=\int_{e}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x\ln x}dx=\ln(\ln x)\bigg|_{x=e}^{n}=\ln(\ln n),
\end{align*}
now $n\ln n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.